# Copy and paste text from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out, how to copy string and paste from JavaScript.

This code example:

```
function copyLink() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

Copies from `myInput` `value`:

```
  <input type="text" value="ttps://site.org/" id="myInput">
```

but I'm trying copy text from variable, not included to `html` `value`:

```
 <button onclick="copyText()">Copy text</button>
```

which is in `.js` to allow user copy/paste:

```
function copyText() {
   var text = "long text...";
   ...
}
```

It looks simple, but seems like I'm searching incorrectly, because I can't find the method.

Comment: var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput").value  might do the trick

Comment: You can also use the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API).

Comment: @user3791775 Hello, you mean adding to myInput, can you provide some example

Comment: document.getElementById("myInput") returns the html, document.getElementById("myInput");.value returns the value of the input. I'm not sure the rest of your code works (the select and setSelectionRange part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create a Dummy element, copy the content and remove it from the dom.

```
// Create a dummy input
var dummy = document.createElement("input");

// Inject the content
dummy.value=copyText;

// Add it to the dom
document.body.appendChild(dummy);

// Select it
dummy.select();

// Copy the content
document.execCommand("copy");

// Clean the dom
document.body.removeChild(dummy);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix, you could just stick the value you want to copy into an input field (even a hidden one), and copy the same way.

Here's a Codepen example: https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/ExKwjjq?editors=1111

```js
function copyText() {
  document.getElementById('hidden').value = new Date().toLocaleString();
  var copyText = document.getElementById('hidden');
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');  
}
```

```html
<input id="hidden" type="text" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: -5em">
<button type="button" onclick="copyText()">Copy</button><br>
<label for="paste">Paste here: <input id="paste" type="text"></label>
```

There's a more advanced API for clipboard operations, however, that's described in this article: https://web.dev/async-clipboard/

Comment: Hello, if I get you correct, I have to hide  myInput document.getElementById("myInput").style.display = "none"; but this way it does not make copy

Comment: I'd hide it using an opacity of 0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Async Clipboard API:

```
async function copy() {
  try {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(input.value);
    console.log('Value copied to clipboard');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
  }
}
```

For more details, please see this [article](https://web.dev/async-clipboard/#writetext()).