# How to paste #text from my #clipboard in <textarea> using only <button>?

Tags: button, textarea, paste

I have a `textarea` and I want to create a `button`.

How do I paste text from my clipboard in this textarea by clicking only in this button?

Look please in the example from **Google Translate**. ("Coller" means paste)

Google Translate application

[image: 1]

Please help me because I do not know how to code.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy and paste text from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63695643/copy-and-paste-text-from-javascript)

Comment: Hello Jordan, thank you. But, what I need is a paste button and not a copy button. For example, if I copy some text from somwhere, I like juste to click in the button and the text will be pasted automaticly in the textarea. I hope you understand me.

Comment: like in the Google Translate application..

Comment: This one includes paste too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579232/simple-copy-paste-function-in-javascript

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I want a button like we find also in Microsoft Word. I do not know if we can create someting like that in html page. Thanks for all your suggestions.